# Get click event of a button placed in App.xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a style in my App.xaml page as shown below

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxMore" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                     <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                        <Button Content="Load More..." Click="btnLoadMore_Click" Name="btnLoadMore"  Visibility="Visible" Background="White" Foreground="Black"></Button>
                     </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am using this style in 4 different pages. I need to get the click event of the "Load More" button in those pages. How can I get this in my windows phone application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Instead, try using a `Command` which you can bind to the ViewModel.

Alternatively, turn your restyled listbox into a custom control and then you can have a centralised eventhandler there.